# Trouble getting Excel VBA Macro to send 1 email while running through range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, email, range, cell

I have tried many different codes for a project that I am working on. I'm have issues setting the conditions, so that it will run through the range ("K3:K17") and range ("L3:L2") and give one straight overall answer if something is less than 1 in either of them. I've been using MsgBox to run my examples so that I don't keep spamming  myself. I feel like I am only getting worse... This is what I have ended up with after trying all sorts of things today.

```
Sub Main()

If IsNumeric(Range("K3:K17").Value) < 1 Then

  MsgBox "Rotations are needed"
Else
  MsgBox "Rotations are not needed"
End If
If IsNumeric(Range("L3:L20").Value) < 1 Then

  MsgBox "Functions are needed"
Else
  MsgBox "Functions are NOT needed"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

> one straight overall answer

-> that means you must be able to do it in one `If` statement.

```
With WorksheetFunction
If .Countif(Range("K3:K17"), "<1") + .Countif(Range("L3:L20"), "<1") > 0 Then
    Msgbox "Functions are needed"
Else
    MsgBox "Functions not needed"
End If
End With
```